# How to prove the equality of these sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm quite new to set theory (and to constructing proofs in general). To prove the equality of $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$, would you just prove that  $A\cup(B\cap C)\subseteq (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$ and that $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)\subseteq A\cup(B\cap C)$? If so, how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure. Pick $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B\cap C$. Suppose $x\in A$. Then $x$ is in $A\cup B$ and $A\cup C$ so $x\in (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$. Now suppose $x\in B\cap C$. Then $x\in B$ and $x\in C$ so $x\in A\cup B$ and $x\in A\cup C$. So in either case $x\in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$. Can you do the other direction?

Comment: Please use the `[elementary-set-theory]` tag for questions like this. Read the description to see what that tag is for, compared to `[set-theory]`.

Answer (score 1):

> prove the equality of $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$

Alternative approach

Prove that LHS and RHS match in the Venn Diagram analog to a truth table chart.

For general problems of this type, with complications, if all else fails, you can consider cases.  Here, there are three pertinent sets, $A,B,$ and $C$.  Therefore, there are 8 possibilities, re a specific element either is or is not in each of $A,B,$ and $C.$

Therefore, all you have to do is construct the appropriate chart.

$$\begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
A & B & C & B\cap C & LHS & A\cup B & A\cup C & RHS \\
\hline
t & t & t & t & t & t & t & t \\
\hline
t & t & f & f & t & t & t & t \\
\hline
t & f & t & f & t & t & t & t \\
\hline
t & f & f & f & t & t & t & t \\
\hline
f & t & t & t & t & t & t & t \\
\hline
f & t & f & f & f & t & f & f \\
\hline
f & f & t & f & f & f & t & f \\
\hline
f & f & f & f & f & f & f & f \\
\hline
\end{array}$$