# Are these two expressions the same?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Imagine that you have 4 sets, $A, B, C,$ and $D$. I was wondering if

$$
(A \cap  B) \cup \left[ (A \cup B) \cap (C \cup D) \right] \cup \left[ (A \cup B) \cap (C \cap D) \right] 
$$
is the same as

$$
(A \cap B) \cup \left[ A \cap (C \cup D) ] \cup [ B \cap (C \cup D) \right] \cup \left[ A \cap (C \cap D) ] \cup [ B \cap (C \cap D) \right]
$$

and if yes (or no), why?

Comment: Did you try a Venn diagram? It might be helpful.

Comment: Try reducing the expressions..then apply venn diagram

Comment: Venn diagrams with 4 sets can be done but not using geometric circles. I think ellipses can work (but forgot the diagram for it).

Comment: Instead of a venn diagram,  you can use a truth table of 16 lines.   Look at "is an element which IS in A, B,C,D" in the LHS,  and then is in the RHS,   then  is in A,B,C but NOT in D,  etc.

Comment: For an illustration of the approach suggested by the previous comments, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045358/how-to-prove-the-equality-of-these-sets/4045425#4045425).

Comment: A more sophisticated graphical technique is that of Karnaugh maps, though that may be overkill here.

Comment: @Semiclassical Definitely overkill, although a few years ago I'd find myself using precisely that to impress myself!

Comment: Personally, I favor the approach of my previous comment because for anything less than  or equal to 4 sets (i.e. $2^4$ possibilities), it is fairly quick, simple, and industrial stength foolproof.  For the given query, that involves A,B,C,D, you can solve it on a piece of scratch paper in less than 15 minutes, **guaranteed**.

Comment: This is one of those situations, where attempting to *elegantly pierce the veil* of the expressions is (in my opinion, totally unnecessary).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Fair. The one thing I'll say in favor of Karnaugh maps here is that the problem is already grouped as AB, CD.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, that part is true! Maybe I should try this, I've been out of touch with Karnaugh maps for nine years now.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes using multiplication and summation notations makes simplification more visible. For left hand
$$(A   B) + \left[ (A + B) (C + D) \right] + \left[ (A + B) C  D) \right]=\\
=A B + (A + B)(C + D+C  D) =\\= A B + (A + B)(C + D)$$
For right hand
$$(A  B) + \left[ A  (C + D) ] + [ B  (C + D) \right] + \left[ A  (C  D) ] + [ B (C  D) \right] = \\
=A  B+(A + B)(C + D)+(A + B)C  D=\\=A B + (A + B)(C + D)$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice the second and third term of the first thing have $A\cup B$ intersecting with two different things, then we take the union of them.  So we can factor out the $A\cup B$ to get $$(A\cup B)\cap [(C\cup D)\cup (C\cap D)]$$
Now note that $C\cap D \subseteq C\cup D$ so that union simplifies to $C\cup D$, thus we get down to
$(A\cup B)\cap (C\cup D)$
put that together with the first term and we have
$$(A\cap B)\cup [(A\cup B)\cap (C\cup D)]$$
So elements of that set are either in BOTH A and B,  or are in one of A or B and also in one of C or D.

Now, can you do the same factoring out in the terms on the second?