# Prove that the formula is a theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can someone give me a hint how to prove that $(r\Rightarrow p)\Rightarrow (p\wedge (q\vee r)\Rightarrow (p\wedge q)\vee r)$ is a theorem? I tried with axioms $r\Rightarrow p \vdash r\Rightarrow p$ and $p\wedge(q\vee r)\vdash p\wedge(q\vee r),$ but I didn't solve it. I tried to use rule for elimination of disjunction:
$\Gamma \vdash \phi\vee\psi ,\qquad \Gamma,\phi\vdash\theta,\qquad \Gamma,\psi\vdash\theta,\qquad$ we have $\Gamma\vdash\theta.$

Comment: I think you’re missing some parentheses here.

Comment: Are you allowed to use truth tables, rather than formal statements, to prove the assertion, or any similar assertion?  If so, then you can use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045358/how-to-prove-the-equality-of-these-sets/4045425#4045425) as an example of how to model your *proof attempt*.

Comment: No, I have to use formal theory, ie. natural deduction.@user2661923

Comment: Please edit your post and add parentheses… right now the formula makes no sense

Comment: Note the antecedent ($r \to p$) is redundant here. If you don't have typos above, you can freely introduce assumption $r \to p$ first and then introduce another assumption $p∧(q∨r)$ to easily derive $(p∧q)∨r$ with $∧, ∨$ Elim and $∨, →$ intro rule to discharge those 2 assumptions at the end of your ND proof...

Answer (score -1):

> I tried to use rule for elimination of disjunction: Γ⊢ϕ∨ψ,Γ,ϕ⊢θ,Γ,ψ⊢θ, we have Γ⊢θ.

That's the core of the proof. $\tfrac{\Gamma~\vdash~\phi\vee\psi\quad \Delta, \phi~\vdash~\theta\quad\Sigma,\psi~\vdash~\theta}{\Gamma\cup\Delta\cup\Sigma~\vdash~ \theta}{\tiny\vee\mathsf E}$

First: Derive $\big[p\land (q\to r)\vdash q\lor r\big]$, $\big[p\land (q\lor r),q\vdash (p\land q)\lor r\big]$, and $\big[r\vdash (p\land q)\lor r\big]$ and then apply the rule of disjunction elimination.

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\vdots}{p\land(q\lor r)\vdash q\lor r}~~\dfrac{\vdots}{p\land (q\lor r),q\vdash(p\land q)\lor r}~~\dfrac{\vdots}{r\vdash(p\land q)\lor r}}{p\land(q\lor r)\vdash(p\land q)\lor r}{\lor\mathsf E}}{\vdots}$$

Next: Build the rest of the proof around this core.