# What is the complement of $A^{c} \cup B^{c} \cup C^{c}$ in terms of $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a probability space $S$, with $A$, $B$ and $C$ some events in $S$. I'd like to simplify $(A^{c} \cup B^{c} \cup C^{c})^{c}$  and write it in terms of $A$, $B$ and $C$. Is this possible? Would it be    $A \cap B \cap C$?

Comment: In general, for problems *similar* to this, I advise constructing a Venn Diagram analog to a truth table chart.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045358/how-to-prove-the-equality-of-these-sets/4045425#4045425) for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the DeMorgan's laws, one has that
\begin{align*}
(A^{c}\cup B^{c}\cup C^{c})^{c} & =((A\cap B\cap C)^{c})^{c} = A\cap B \cap C 
\end{align*}

**EDIT**

Answering your comment, one has that:
\begin{align*}
A^{c}\cup B^{c}\cup C^{c} & = (A^{c}\cup B^{c})\cup C^{c}\\\\
& = (A\cap B)^{c}\cup C^{c}\\\\
& = ((A\cap B)\cap C)^{c}\\\\
& = (A\cap B\cap C)^{c}
\end{align*}

which implies the desired result.

Comment: How do DeMorgan's work here exactly for 3 sets? @Atila Correia

Comment: @Sasha1001 I have edited my answer. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Generally, the complement of a union is the intersection of the complements, i.e.

$$\left( \bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_i \right)^c = \bigcap_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_i^c$$

and the complement of an intersection is the union of the complements, i.e.

$$\left( \bigcap_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_i \right)^c = \bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_i^c$$